# Problems about using AQS in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, search, windows-search, file-search

I'm testing `Windows 7` and trying to do [`AQS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa965711(v=vs.85).aspx). I saw an image in about `filtering result by type` [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/73065/learn-the-advanced-search-operators-in-windows-7/):

[image]

But when I try "`type:`" in search box, it does not provide any option in drop down menu. Why this occur and how I can solve this problem?

Edit:

I add images from ***My*** PC:

This image shows "filters" of `Windows search` (<kbd>Win + F</kbd>) and you can see "type" is there:

[image]

This image shows "type" filters is available in`Windows search` (<kbd>Win + F</kbd>) and has a drop down list of options:

[image]

This image shows "search filters" after pressing <kbd>F3</kbd> on File explorer of `Windows 7` and you can see there is not "type" filter:

[image]

1. Why <kbd>WIN+ F</kbd> has "type:" filter in tiny box under search box but when I browse to a real directory, proposed filters does not propose "type" filter?
2. Is [this image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Windows_Vista_Search.png) also for windows 7?
3. What is difference between "type:" filter and "kind:" filter?

Comment: For one, that link you provided on AQS does not provide Type: as being available. If you mean type is a kind of suffix (jpg, png, mpg), then just type the suffix or use a wildcard *.jpg.

Comment: @HumorMe And what about above image?

Comment: @hasanghaforian It's either based on the current results (try pressing Enter after searching?), or it's a history of `type` filters that have been used previously.

Comment: Those "types" are not types but merely file extensions. Maybe with the added benefit of DOC and JPEG covering multiple extensions. If you look at the the article you linked the closest match would probably be `kind` which IMO would be way more what a "type" of file would be. Or you could use `ext`. As for your screenshot where did you find it? Depending on it, it might have been a thing for another/older Windows 7 version.

Comment: @oldmud0 It seems It is not based on the current results or historical search.  I edited question, please see it again.

Comment: @Seth I edited my question. Please see it again. As you can see, there are different `Filter` proposed for search in one instance of `windows 7` (which is ***my*** PC)

Comment: Those images are your own personal history searches. There is no default lists. Try `type:monster`, it will appear on your next search.

Answer (score 0):

**Multiple file types in a search. Windows.**

**Specific case: "images"**

It seems that type isn't listed in your link that you provided. But it will work anyhow with image file-types (**png, jpg, jpeg, bmp, or other extensions**). Just use it combined with the **OR operator**, like this:

Using keyword `ext`

```
ext:png OR ext:jpg OR ext:bmp OR ext:jpeg
```

or use the keyword `type`

```
type:png OR type:jpg OR type:bmp OR type:jpeg
```

Search music? Music is stored in various forms. The most popular are: mp3 and wav

```
type:mp3 OR type:wav
```

**This history goes with the Object you are using. Different history for different searches on different window sessions.**

[image]
[image]

Comment: I edited my question and added more details and some specific questions. Please see it again.

Comment: it should still be valid. There is a long hand, and a graphical user interface, but the results are the same.

Comment: @hasanghaforian Oh. I think I get your misunderstanding now. Type:music isn't an option. Music is a human construct of sounds, but to search for "music", on a computer, you'd search for `type:mp3 OR type:wav`, which are extensions that signify a file type.